# NServiceBus: Does MSMQ go to "sleep"?

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

Normally messages with NServiceBus seem to be transferred pretty fast, but it seems like if I haven't sent any messages for a while, it takes a few seconds for them to be received.  Does anyone know why that would be?  If MSMQ is indeed "going to sleep" is there a setting to "keep it awake"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting this is because MSMQ keeps idle connections open for only so long.  If this is an issue check out the Idle Timeout registry setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922753.aspx